# Iframe Load Too FAST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I setup script to load my iframe but i see that script load to fast iframe content, i dont know how can setup to backgound load all css images content and then show full iframe content?

My code:

```
<style>
#test123 {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$('iframe').on('load', function() {
    jQuery("#test123").css("display","block");
},)
});
</script>
```

```
<iframe id="test123" src="https://www.mydomain.co/iframe" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: Does the iframe load content dynamically? There's no event that waits for that automatically.

Comment: The only way to wait for that is to use `postMessage()` from the iframe when it has finished loading everything.

Comment: that is java script? how can i implement in my code can you pls try to write code to i see what you exactly mean? @Barmar

Answer (score 2):

Why don´t you try a setTimeOut function to delay the iframe? Not fancy, but it should work.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $('iframe').on('load', function() {
      setTimeout(function () {
         jQuery("#test123").css("display","block");
      }, 2000); // 2 seconds
   },)
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that in other country example "Indonesia or Australia" need more than 8 seconds to load that iframe. I want to make script that when page is 100% loaded to show in my blog post @DiegoGraziano